# ¿Por qué al iterar una lista recibo el error "TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, bucles, yield

Tengo una duda con las listas en Python. Mi código es el siguiente:

```
frases = ["Practical GUI", "Advanced Programming", "Building Intelligent", "The AI Workshop", "Data Analysis"]
def enumerador(f, i):
    while i <= len(f):
        print(i)
        yield i
        i += 1

for i, frase in enumerador(frases, 1):
    print("Book {}: {}".format(i, frase))
```

El resultado esperado es:

```
Book 1: Practical GUI
Book 2: Advanced Programming
```

... y así con los elementos de la lista.

El problema es que me muestra el error:

```
TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
```

La verdad no termino de comprender qué estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: A menos que hayan pedido en un ejercicio que escribas el generador `enumerador()`, no necesitas hacerlo pues Python ya te da esa funcionalidad resuelta con `enumerate()`.

Comment: En cuanto al error, literalmente significa "No puedo desempaquetar un objeto no iterable". Se refiere a cuando intentas asignar varias variables en el lado izquierdo de la asignación y una variable en el lado derecho, con algo como: `a, b, c = x`. Para que eso funcione `x` tiene que ser iterable y así python interará por `x` (esperando tres valores) y asignará cada uno a `a`, `b` y `c` respectivamente. Si `x` no es iterable no puede hacerlo. Eso te pasa en el `for i, frase` puesto que tu `enumerador()` retorna un solo valor en vez de dos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Casi, casi:

```
frases = ["Practical GUI", "Advanced Programming", "Building Intelligent", "The AI Workshop", "Data Analysis"]
def enumerador(f, i):
    while i < len(f):
        print(i)
        yield i, f[i]
        i += 1


for i, frase in enumerador(frases, 1):
    print("Book {}: {}".format(i, frase))
```

Primero, `enumerador` tiene que retornar dos valores cada vez: el indice y el título:

```
yield i, f[i]
```

Segundo, cuidado con los limites. Es "<" en lugar de "<=":

```
while i < len(f):
```

Produce:

```
1
Book 1: Advanced Programming
2
Book 2: Building Intelligent
3
Book 3: The AI Workshop
4
Book 4: Data Analysis
```

Tal vez deberías empezar de cero si quieres cubrir toda la lista:

```
for i, frase in enumerador(frases, 0):
```

Answer (score 2):

Este error sucede cuando no tienes elementos para iterar. Esto, como te indica @Candid, es porque no estás devolviendo el título que luego intentas iterar.

Y podrás verlo, si si convertimos el objeto que devuelve el método a lista:

```
a = enumerador(frases, 1)
print(list(a))
```

Vemos que devuelve lo siguiente:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Una vez corregido como él indica:

```
...
while i < len(f):
        yield i, f[i]
...
```

Verás que ahora devuelve una lista con tuplas con par de elementos cada una, por lo que podrás iterar tanto un elemento como otro:

```
[(1, 'Advanced Programming'), (2, 'Building Intelligent'), (3, 'The AI Workshop'), (4, 'Data Analysis')]
```

Entre tantas formas de solventarlo:

- **Podrías ir a la vía fácil con un contador**:

```
frases = ["Practical GUI", "Advanced Programming", "Building Intelligent", "The AI Workshop", "Data Analysis"]

counter = 1

for i in frases:
    print("Book {}: {}".format(i, counter))
    counter += 1
```

- **Podrías usar el método** [enumerate](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0279/) **que ya te indica en qué posición estás**:

```
frases = ["Practical GUI", "Advanced Programming", "Building Intelligent", "The AI Workshop", "Data Analysis"]

for indice, valor in enumerate(frases):
    print("Book {}: {}".format(indice + 1, valor))
```

Todos **con resultado**:

```
Book Practical GUI: 1
Book Advanced Programming: 2
Book Building Intelligent: 3
Book The AI Workshop: 4
Book Data Analysis: 5
```